# Error: Missing required argument count for minting. Please provide the argument in the mintParams

Tags: nft, crossmint

I am trying to implement crossmint-pay-button using javascript.
I am using cdn link: https://unpkg.com/@crossmint/client-sdk-vanilla-ui@0.0.1-alpha.1/lib/index.global.js

```
<crossmint-pay-button
     collectionTitle="Gaia comic"
     collectionDescription="Gaia comic collection "
     collectionPhoto=""
     clientId="8d77450f.....ad497f612"
     mintConfig='{"type":"erc-721","price":"0.1","_count":"1"}'
     environment="staging"
/>
```

When I click Pay button below error gets.
"Missing required argument count for minting. Please provide the argument in the mintParams"

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The error message is misleading. Where it says `mintParams`, it should say `mintConfig`.

With that in mind: what error is saying is that your contract abi is expecting a `count` argument to mint, and this argument should be passed in the `mintConfig` object.

In your case, you are passing the argument `_count`. If you rename it to `count`, that should work.

See below:

```
    <crossmint-pay-button
     collectionTitle="Gaia comic"
     collectionDescription="Gaia comic collection "
     collectionPhoto=""
     clientId="8d77450f.....ad497f612"
     mintConfig='{"type":"erc-721","price":"0.1","count":"1"}'
     environment="staging"
    />
```

Reach out to the crossmint team on discord if this doesn't work for you!

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I renamed it to "count" but still not working. Giving same error. I raised this issue on discord with the team but they asked me to post in stackoverflow.

Comment: Mind adding a screenshot of the error you see if you use this code snippet? I believe it may be a different error

Comment: @alfongj  yes your are right, now the error is different. It says "Missing required argument to for minting. Please provide the argument in the mintParams"